# What are the values ​of $a$, one of the roots of the equation is greater than $1$ and the other is less than $1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, quadratic-forms

> What are the values ​​of $a$, one of the roots of the equation is greater than $1$ and the other is less than $1$? $$(2a+1)x^2-ax+a-2=0$$

I tried Vieta's formulas for quadratic equation, but I could not get the correct solution:

$x_1+x_2= \frac {a}{2a+1},  x_1×x_2= \frac {a-2}{2a+1}$

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite the question by shifting the x-axis by 1 to the right (substitute $x=y-1$) so that one root is less that 0 and the other one is greater than 0, and Proceed in your way. The second Vieta's formula will look better.

Answer (score 1):

Distinguish cases $2a+1\lt 0$, $=0$ (impossible given there are two roots), $\gt 0$.

- If $2a+1\gt 0$, the statement is equivalent to the statement that the quadratic function $(2a+1)x^2-ax+a-2$ is *negative* at $x=1$, i.e. $2a-1\lt 0$, so we have $a\in (-1/2, 1/2) $.
- If $2a+1\lt 0$, the statement is equivalent to the statement that the quadratic function $(2a+1)x^2-ax+a-2$ is *positive* at $x=1$, i.e. $2a-1\gt 0$. This has no solutions.

The overall solution is: $a\in (-1/2, 1/2) $.

Comment: So the correct answer is (D).

Comment: Thank you..but I dont understand your solution still yet. :(..

Comment: You need to know basic properties of quadratic functions, such as that the graph of $f (x)=ax^2+bx+c $ is a parabola facing "down" (convex) if $a\gt 0$, or a parabola facing "up" (concave) if $a\lt 0$. It means, if it has two roots $x_1$ and $x_2$, that, for $a\gt 0$ we have $f (x)\gt 0$ on $x\in(-\infty,x_1)\cup (x_2,+\infty) $ and $f (x)\lt 0$ on $x\in (x_1,x_2) $; when $a\lt 0$, the inequalities are reversed. Does that help?

Comment: thank you so much. I try to understand again...